# How can I extract an exact set of words from a string using a regex?

Tags: regex

I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find a question that answers this specific use case (maybe I've missed it). But basically I'm wanting to extract the following text from a string: `Welcome James:`

This text **must** be at the start of the string, e.g:

**Welcome James: Now some text follows...blahblah** - This would be a match

However

**This is some text Welcome James: some more text...** - This would ***not*** be a match.

So basically I'd hard code `Welcome James:` into the regex (I don't need any other variables of `Welcome <name>:`.

Is this possible? All I've been able to find is regexes that match **single** words *without* spaces or characters.

Comment: ^(Welcome James)

Comment: @sheplu Awesome that worked perfectly, post an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search at the start of a string, just prefix the regex with the `^` (caret) character:

```
/^Welcome James/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :) But @charles gave it too!

```
^(Welcome James)
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah I will accept his then, as it was first :)